# Php change time format

Tags: php, date

I want to change the time format using php but I can not get it right.
The loaded value `(delivery_eta)` got the time format `Ymd`, so for example `20180925`.

But I want to change that to Tuesday 25 September 2018.

My current code:

```
<?php $locale = 'nl_NL'; $date = new Zend_Date($_product->getData('delivery_eta'),'Ymd'); $date->setLocale($locale);echo $date->toString(Zend_Date::DATE_FULL);?>
```

No the output is:

Sunday 9 January 20

What am I missing?

Comment: See this examples https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.date.constants.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date("l d Y", $_product->getData('delivery_eta'));
```